# Retrieve company name from companymetadata in Intuit IPP devkit QBO

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to retrieve the company name from `companymetadata`. I have this which doesn't work.

```
    Dim oauthValidator As New OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret)
    Dim context As New ServiceContext(oauthValidator, apptoken, realmid, IntuitServicesType.QBO)
    Dim commonService As New DataServices(context)
    Dim actualCompanyMetaData As Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CompanyMetaData = TryCast(commonService.FindById(New Qbo.CompanyMetaData()), Qbo.CompanyMetaData)

    Dim cpnyname As String = actualCompanyMetaData.CompanyFileName.ToString
```

How do I get the company name?

Comment: Hi Don, Can you provide more info? Did the API call succeed? Can you grab the request and response so we can look at any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returned in the QBNRegisteredCompanyName property:

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CompanyMetaData actualCompanyMetaData =commonService.FindById(new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CompanyMetaData();
string cpnyname = actualCompanyMetaData.QBNRegisteredCompanyName;
```

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online/CompanyMetaData

Answer (score 0):

In QBO v3

```
var dataService = new DataService(context);
var company = dataService.FindById(new Company { Id = oauthAccessToken.RealmId});
return company.CompanyName;
```

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO